# Inconsistent Functionality of Lowdb Adapter

Tags: json, typescript, lowdb

"I'm using Lowdb in an existing template, meaning I have to use this tool even though I don't have much experience with it. In a specific section of the code, I'm encountering an error: 'Argument of type 'AdapterSync' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Adapter'. Property 'read' is missing in type 'AdapterSync' but required in type 'Adapter'.ts(2345) Low.d.ts(2, 5): 'read' is declared here.  I'm not sure what's causing this error."

**The code**

```TS
import jsonServer from "json-server";
import path from "path";
import {Low } from 'lowdb';
import FileSync from "lowdb/adapters/FileSync.js";
//import { JSONFileSync } from 'lowdb/node'
//import { JSONFile, JSONFileSync } from "lowdb/adapters/FileSync.js";
import { TiendanubeAuthInterface } from "../features/auth/interfaces/tiendanube-auth.interface.js";
import { HttpErrorException } from "../utils/HttpErrorException.js";

/**
 * this repository is temporary, please use real database to production mode
 */

const userRepository = jsonServer.router(path.resolve("db.json"));

const server = jsonServer.create();
const middleware = jsonServer.defaults();

server.use(middleware);
server.use(userRepository);

interface IDatabase {
  credentials: TiendanubeAuthInterface[];
}
type Data = {
  access_token?: string;
  token_type?: string;
  scope?: string;
  user_id?: number;
  error?: string;
  error_description?: string;
}

const defaultData: Data = {};
const adapter = new FileSync<Data>(path.resolve("db.json"));
const database =   new Low(adapter,defaultData);

class UserRepository {
  save(credential: TiendanubeAuthInterface) {
    this.createOrUpdate(credential);
  }

  findOne(user_id: number) {
    const credentials = database.get("credentials").value();
    const store = this.findValueFromProperty<TiendanubeAuthInterface, number>(
      "user_id",
      credentials,
      user_id
    );

    if (!store) {
      throw new HttpErrorException(`${user_id} not found`).setStatusCode(404);
    }

    return store;
  }

  findFirst(): TiendanubeAuthInterface {
    return database.get("credentials").value()?.[0];
  }

  private createOrUpdate(data: TiendanubeAuthInterface) {
    const credentials = database.get("credentials").value();
    const hasCredentials = this.findValueFromProperty<TiendanubeAuthInterface>(
      "user_id",
      credentials,
      data.user_id
    );

    if (hasCredentials) {
      const index = credentials.findIndex(
        (credential) => credential.user_id === data.user_id
      );
      credentials.splice(index, 1, data);
    } else {
      credentials.push(data);
    }
    database.set("credentials", credentials).write();
  }

  private findValueFromProperty<T, K = any>(
    property: string,
    list: T[],
    value: K
  ): T | undefined {
    const findValue = list?.find(
      (values) => (values as any)[property] === value
    );

    return findValue;
  }
}

export default new UserRepository();
```

I've already modified a portion of the code to:

```ts
const defaultData: Data = {};
const adapter = new FileSync<IDatabase>(path.resolve("db.json"));
const database =   new Low(adapter,defaultData);
```

However, the error was:

```
Argument of type 'AdapterSync<IDatabase>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Adapter<Data>'.
  Property 'read' is missing in type 'AdapterSync<IDatabase>' but required in type 'Adapter<Data>'.ts(2345)
Low.d.ts(2, 5): 'read' is declared here.
const adapter: Lowdb.AdapterSync<IDatabase>
```

> I'm running out of ideas, and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.